# Vector reflection with limited angle

Tags: vectors, reflection

I am struggling with following challenge in my free time programming project $-$ how is it possible to make reflection vector that reflects along normal with angle that is not larger than some $\alpha$?

[image: Example of normal and limited angle reflection]

I have already seen classical reflection formula $ r = d - 2 (d \cdot n) n $, which unfortunately does not provide answer to my problem.

I tried to fiddle around with JS atan2() function, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors), but it didn't work for all cases and I would appreciate some elegant general solution instead of patching special cases.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying to understand the problem: The usual rule is input angle equals output angle. So it just a matter of calculation. I assume your problem has an additional rule that there is no reflection for angles greater than a given maximum angle.

Comment: Well, as I already commented, I was looking for solution that would somehow correct "shallow" reflection. It seems @john-hughes provided answer I was looking for. Let's say vectors operations are just not my cup of tea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming $n$ is a unit vector.

1. If $d \cdot n \le 0$: ERROR
2. $\alpha = \arccos(d \cdot n)$
3. If $\alpha < \alpha_\text{max}$, return $r = d - 2(d \cdot n) n$
4. Else, $v = d - (d \cdot n) n$ is a vector perpendicular to $n$, on the $d$ side of the $nd$ plane.
5. Let $w = \frac{1}{\|v\|} v$.
6. Set $r = \cos(\alpha_\text{max}) n - \sin(\alpha_\text{max}) w$; return $r$.

What I've done is test as @mvw suggests, and when the test fails, I've computed a vector in the $dn$-plane whose angle *is* the max angle, and then computed its reflection.

Comment: Although haven't tried it yet, looks pretty much like something I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I fail to see your problem but just use the scalar product
$$
u \cdot n = \lVert u \rVert \cos \alpha
$$

So test for
$$
\frac{\sum_i u_i n_i}{\sqrt{\sum_i u_i^2}} = \frac{u \cdot n}{\lVert u \rVert} \ge \cos \alpha_{\tiny \mbox{max}}
$$

to see if $\alpha \le \alpha_{\tiny \mbox{max}}$ for the tested vector $u$.

Comment: Sorry for unclarity. I don't want to just test the angle, I need to get reflection vector that has angle $\alpha_{new}$ in range $<0, \alpha_{max}>$. In other words, although angle between $source$ and $normal$ is original $\alpha$, **I want to get $target$ vector** with angle $\alpha_{new}$ that does not overflow my specified maximum angle $\alpha_{max}$.